# Powershell log - count errors

Tags: powershell, logging, networking

I have a basic Powershell script which logs network activity (tracert, nslookup, ping) to a log file. A new log file is created for every new day.

I would like to update the script to also save information of error occurrences.
I have an array of possible errors (I am interested in) and when saving the information to log file I would like to have any error recorded - only count per error.

I am ok to have error counts saved in text file in this form:
error_name*count|error_name*count .. etc
So for example:
Host Not Available*10|Request Timed Out*22 .. etc

So let's say I have this array with errors:

```
$errors = @('error1','error2','error3')
```

I save the results to log file like this:

```
tracert $server >> $logFile
nslookup $server >> $logFile
ping $server >> $logFile
```

I tried to save output to variable and match it against the array:

```
tracert $server >> $logFile
$data = tracert $server
if ($null -ne ($errors | ? { $data -match $_ })) {
    #reading data from report file
    $data = Get-Content $reportFile
    $d1 = $data.split('|')
    $err = @()
    foreach ($item in $d) {
        $count = $item.split('*')
        $err += $count[1]
    }
}
```

What I am not able to figure out is how to get array key so the correct number of errors is read from report file and can be increased if error occurs and then save the file again. Maybe there is some other, easier solution?
I will appreciate any help or hint.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a try/catch:

```
try{tracert $server >> $logFile}
catch{$_.Exception.Message}
```

Put the real code in try block and if it fails, then it will come to catch block and `$_.Exception.Message` will capture the error message. If you wish to get the entire Error then you can use `$Error` in catch block.

Now you can change the script accordingly and can remove the `if` logic.

Since you already have the possible error codes, you can put the `Switch case` in the catch block with the possible cause by doing string match and can put your own sentences.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that rather than creating your own custom output format that you then have to handle via string manipulation, use one of the structured formats that PowerShell already gives you access to. For example, JSON.

Here's how I might write this:

```
Function Out-ErrorLog {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [String]$Data,

        [String]$LogPath = '.\error.log',

        [String[]]$Errors  = @('Request Timed Out','Host Not Available')
    )
    Process {
        If (Test-Path $LogPath) { 
            Write-Verbose "Loading existing error log file from $LogPath.."
            $ErrorLog = Get-Content $LogPath | ConvertFrom-Json
        } Else {
            $ErrorLog = New-Object -TypeName PSObject 
        }

        ForEach ($Err in $Errors) { 
            $Matches = $Data | Select-String -SimpleMatch $Err -AllMatches

            If ($Matches) {
                If (-Not $ErrorLog.$Err) {
                    Write-Verbose "Creating $Err property.."
                    $ErrorLog | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $Err -Value $Matches.count
                } Else {
                    Write-Verbose "Adding to $Err count.."
                    $ErrorLog.$Err += $Matches.count 
                }
            }
        } 

        Write-Verbose "Outputting Errors to $LogPath.."
        $ErrorLog | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File $LogPath -Encoding UTF8
    }
}

$Server  = '1.2.3.4'

$Data = ping $Server
$Data >> $LogFile
$Data | Out-ErrorLog -Verbose

$Data = tracert $Server
$Data >> $LogFile
$Data | Out-ErrorLog -Verbose

$Data = nslookup $server
$Data >> $LogFile
$Data | Out-ErrorLog -Verbose
```

I've written an `Out-ErrorLog` function to save on code repetition. This takes `$Data` as input from the pipeline, and has two other parameters `$LogPath` for where you want errors to be recorded as a file and the array of `$Errors` you want to test for/record.

It then uses `Test-Path` to see if its log file already exists, if it does it loads it and converts its content from Json.

We then use `ForEach` to loop through the error options and match them against the data provided. We use `Select-String` for this and the `-AllMatches` parameter so we can get an easy count of how many of error occurred.

If an error has occurred, then we check to see if we have it already in the `$ErrorLog` object. If we don't then we create a new property in our object for that error and give it the value of the count. If it did already exist then we just increment it.

When the loop concludes  we output the resultant ErrorLog object as a Json file.